# ng-repeat renders data but doesn't show on screen

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

using ionic framework, i want to grab categories data from php backend and show them.

html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
<div ng-controller="CategoryCtrl" ng-init="getCategories()">

    <div ng-repeat="category in categories" style="border:1px solid red;">
        {{category.name}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

js

```
.controller('CategoryCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {
    $scope.getCategories = function(){                    
        $http.get('http://localhost/test/server/test.php').then(function(response){
            $scope.categories = response;
        });
    }  
}
```

php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Categories";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

problem is that in chrome console i can see the data

```
            <!-- ngRepeat: category in categories --><div ng-repeat="category in categories" style="border:1px solid red;" class="ng-binding">
                abc
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories --><div ng-repeat="category in categories" style="border:1px solid red;" class="ng-binding">
                def
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories --><div ng-repeat="category in categories" style="border:1px solid red;" class="ng-binding">
                ghi
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories --><div ng-repeat="category in categories" style="border:1px solid red;" class="ng-binding">
                jkl
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: category in categories -->
```

but can't make it show on the screen.

Comment: in chrome console you can see "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" - these are the categories

Comment: if the console shows that the DOM elements have been generated, then it has to do something with the styling of the container element. the php code is not relevant here.

Comment: Be sure that `z-index` configured properly. Maybe something else hides the array

Comment: check the css, it must be hidden or something, as @AbhinavGujjar said

Comment: it also may be to do with the fact that this is all wrapped up in a template. Where are you referencing this "home.html"?

Comment: yes, it was just that. .pane, .view {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;